# high memory usage or good quality tradeofs while working with large images stored in a array

Tags: ios, swift, memory-leaks, uiimageview

I have a view controller like this:

[image]

There is an ImageView and a RangeSlider.

The behavior should be this:
If the user slides the range slider, the image in the ImageView should switch to a new image inside an array of images. The user also can do zooming operations on the image without losing the quality of the pictures.

So what I did was to download the images into the image array on `viewDidLoad`:

```
//image array
var images = [UIImage]()
```

I'm downloading 48 images with the size of 1920 × 1920 px and about 120 KB per image and creating `UIImage` objects of the downloaded data and saving them into the array like this:

```
DispatchQueue.global().async { [weak self] in
    let data = try? Data(contentsOf: url) 
    DispatchQueue.main.async {
        if data != nil {
            let img = UIImage(data: data!)
            self?.images.append(img!)
        } else {
            ...
        }
    }
}
```

To change the image inside the imageView I created this function:

```
func updateImage(currentImage: UIImage) {
    self.imageView.image = currentImage
}
```

When the user starts to slide the `rangeSlider` the memory usage of the app runs from 40 MB to 700 MB and stops increasing after the user switched all the images through. After that point the user can switch the whole images back and forward without any effect on the memory usage.

But when I do a little resizing before updating the image, the memory issue gets solved but the images are now low quality if the user zooms a bit.

Resizing part:

```
extension UIImage {
    func resized(_ newSize:CGSize) -> UIImage {
        UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions(newSize, false, 0)
        self.draw(in: CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: newSize.width, height: newSize.height))
        let newImage = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext()
        UIGraphicsEndImageContext()

        return newImage!
    }
}

func updateImage(currentImage: UIImage) {
    let currentImg = currentImage.resized(self.imageView.bounds.size)

    self.imageView.image = currentImg
}
```

And for zooming I use this:

```
@IBAction func scaleImage(_ sender: UIPinchGestureRecognizer) {
    print(self.imageView.transform)

    let tmp = self.imageView.transform.scaledBy(x: sender.scale, y: sender.scale)

    if (tmp.a >= 0.99 || tmp.d >= 0.99) && (tmp.a < 2.5 || tmp.d < 2.5) {
        self.imageView.transform = self.imageView.transform.scaledBy(x: sender.scale, y: sender.scale)
        sender.scale = 1

        if (tmp.a <= 1.2 || tmp.d <= 1.2) {
            self.imageView.center = defaultImageCenter
        }
    }
}
```

So how can I achieve it in a elegant way to provide no memory leaks but still use the best image quality?

Comment: Is it completely necessary to download them all at the same time?

Comment: yes it is because it should have a great user experience without lagging content.

Comment: most apps that do something like this load a couple images ahead but not all at once

Comment: Just so you are clear, what you are seeing is memory use, not memory leaks. A leak is when memory is allocated and can never be reclaimed. This isn't what you have here. Unless you are having issues with memory pressure you may not want to do anything. You can use an NSCache or a framework like SDWebImage to manage loading on demand

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
if data != nil {
   let img = UIImage(data: data!)
   self?.images.append(img!)
}
```

At this part, instead of creating a UIImage and adding it to an array, just save the data to the disk and store its location an array. Then when you move the slider, create the UIImage from the location matching the slider's position. This way there will be only one UIImage loaded in the memory at a time.

If you want to make it faster, load also the previous and next image (for example you are at position 4, load images 3 and 5 too, then when you move the slider to position 5, you will already have the image - at this point release image 3 and load 6). This will have a larger memory footprint, but when you move the slider you will see the images immediately.

You might also want to not download all the images at once to make this faster, but that's not related to memory, so this should be enough for your problem.